# How to read and write arff file in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ascii, arff

I don't know arff before. But now I've to do some data-mining stuff in ruby on rails using arff file.Is there any way to read arff file in ruby on rails?

For now I've found couple of gems who write to arff but they have limitations

https://github.com/wwood/rarff

https://github.com/andypayne/rarff

also I've found some code of reading and writing to arrff in ruby. below is the link:

https://github.com/mikiobraun/dataformat/blob/master/ruby/arff.rb

Comment: Are you asking us to show you how to use the gems? Have you tried using them?

Comment: No I'm asking the efficient way. Btw gems only used for write there not read arff file.

Comment: Then show us what you wrote, and explain why you feel that it's not "efficient".

Comment: I'm following the 3rd link